# Blazor: Range type input's OnHold scenario (possible?)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Is it possible to get the actual 'onHold' data of a slider kind input in Blazor?
Below you can see the code I created. As you may know, this way every time I press the button, I get back the current state of the slider, but I am willing to update the '@printnumber' as I am moving the slider, in real-time.

```
<p>Number:</p>
<input type="range" min="3" max="50" step="1" @bind="actualNumber" />
<p>@printNumber</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Calc" >Click me</button>

@code
{
    private int actualNumber;
    private int printNumber;

    public void Calc()
    {
        printNumber = actualNumber;
    }

}
```

I have been looking for a solution but didn't find any right scenario to solve this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like the following:

```
@page "/"

<p>Number:</p>
<input type="range" min="3" max="50" step="1" @bind="@actualNumber" 
@bind:event="oninput"/>


<p>@actualNumber</p>

@code
{
   private int actualNumber { get; set; } = 10;

}
```

Note: @bind is a compiler directive instructing the compiler to produce code that bound the slider's value attribute to the property actualNumber, and to create a change event handler to update the property actualNumber from the slider's value( See below a sample where I do this manually ). This is the default behavior, but you can instruct the compiler to use the input event instead of the change event so that the change is immediate.

You can do it like the following:

```
@page "/"

<p>Number:</p>
<input type="range" min="3" max="50" step="1" @bind- 
          value="@actualNumber" @bind-value:event="oninput"/>


<p>@actualNumber</p>

@code
{
   private int actualNumber { get; set; } = 10;

}
```

You can also do it like this:

```
@page "/"

<p>Number:</p>
<input type="range" min="3" max="50" step="1" value="@actualNumber" @oninput="@((args) => Calc(args.Value.ToString()))"/>



<p>@actualNumber</p>


@code
{
    private int actualNumber { get; set; } = 10;


    public void Calc(string step)
    {
        actualNumber = Convert.ToInt32(step);
    }

}
```

You can also do it like this:

```
@page "/"

<p>Number:</p>

<input type="range" min="3" max="50" step="1" value="@actualNumber" 
@oninput="@((args) => actualNumber = Convert.ToInt32( args.Value))" />


<p>@actualNumber</p>

@code
{
   private int actualNumber { get; set; } = 10;

}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

For two way binding I always prefer to inherit from `InputBase`. Since range has the ability to bind to different types and not just `int` we can also make use of a `typeparam` to pass in the type of the bound property. Inheriting from `InputBase` also gives us the advantage of automatically handling validation and validation styling to match the rest of your application.

Although the binding will automatically take care of the *OnHold* data this solution raises an event any time the slider is changed. This gives you the ability to execute code as the value changes. In the event, the parent will have access to the previous value and the current value. This can be very useful for validating the range component in real time by locking or reverting the selection based on your needs.

**RangeComponent.razor**

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@using Flash.Models.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

@typeparam TItem
@inherits InputBase<TItem>

<div class="form-floating @ContainerCss" style="@ContainerStyle">
    <input type="range" class="form-control @CssClass @InputCssClass" id="@Id" @bind="@CurrentValueAsString" min="@Min" max="@Max" @oninput="InvokeOnInput">
    <label for="@Id" class="@LabelCss">  <span class="@LabelIconCss"></span> @Label</label>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TItem> OnInput { get; set; }
    private async Task InvokeOnInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = (TItem)Convert.ChangeType(args.Value, typeof(TItem));
            OnInput.InvokeAsync(result);
        }
        catch { }// ignore the exception, attempted to bind invalid value.
    
    }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Expression<Func<TItem>> ValidationFor { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public string? Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string InputCssClass { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string LabelCss { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string ContainerCss { get; set; } 
    [Parameter] public string ContainerStyle { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string LabelIconCss { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter] public int Min {get;set;} = 0;
    [Parameter] public int Max {get;set;} = 550;
    
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out TItem result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        var success = false;
        result = default;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            try
            {
                result = (TItem)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TItem));
                success = true;
                OnInput.InvokeAsync(result);
            }
            catch { } // ignore the exception and return false
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

**SomeParent.razor**

The `Label` declaration looks messy but only because I'm using `string.Format` to demonstrate the `_someModel.property` two way binding.

```
<RangeComponent TItem="int" @bind-Value="_someModel.property" ValidationFor="@(()=>_someModel.property)" Label="@string.Format("Range ({0})", _someModel.property)" Min="1" Max="50" OnInput="@RangeChanged"></RangeComponent>

private async Task RangeChanged(int current)
{

    int previousRange = _someModel.property;
    int currentRange = current;
 
}
```

My component is designed based of bootstrap 5 `Floating labels` to match the rest of my application but that's a personal preference.

**RangeComponent.razor.css**

```
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    accent-color: white;
}

/***** Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Edge Chromium *****/
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #6c757d;
    height: 1rem;
}

/******** Firefox ********/
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    background: #6c757d;
    height: 1rem;
}
```

**Final Result**
[image]